# How to get back the old debugger in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, debugger

Firefox 52 introduces a new JavaScript Debugger with new UI but lack of many features that the old one has. One that I found critical and can't work without is the ability to search for some text in all files. So how can I get back the old debugger?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Firefox 52 or later and need to switch back to the old Debugger, you can do so by visiting [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) and setting the `devtools.debugger.new-debugger-frontend` preference to `false` as [explained on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger).

Comment: While that's true, the related preference will be removed in a future version of Firefox (hopefully when the new UI has feature parity with the old one).

Comment: Sadly, the preference no longer works (Firefox 68) and the new UI [does not have all of the features of the old Debugger](https://superuser.com/q/1469699/45163).