# How do I modify a variable in Firefox Debugger?

Tags: firefox, debugger, firefox-developer-tools

I would like to be able to edit a variable after setting (and hitting) a breakpoint, or simply pausing execution, in either Firefox or Firefox Developer Edition.

It seems that it [used to have this feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Examine,_modify,_and_watch_variables#Modify_variables), but it was removed when the debugger was reimplemented.

There used to be [a way to get the old debugger back](https://superuser.com/questions/1165409/how-to-get-back-the-old-debugger-in-firefox), but I have tried this and it no longer works.

I will accept answers that recommend addons.

Answer (score 8):

The way I do it is to simply type the new variable into the debug console with the new value. For example, I would type: `myobj.myprop = newval;`<kbd>Enter</kbd>. No different from writing javascript. As long as the variable you are trying to change is in scope at your break point (and not initialized with `const`), it should work fine.

Comment: It looks like it is not working, for example with the code https://codepen.io/iksdatoo/pen/JbbQoz if we set a breakpoint on the first button click event function at line `React.createElement('button', {`, then execute `this.clickMe = null;` in the console when the execution is stopped at the breakpoint and then resume, the function is still executed when clicking on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Watch Expression for the variable. When the breakpoint hits, double-click the variable in the watch expressions list to get an editable field. Type in an assignment statement, e.g., `myVar=newValue`. It works with or without a semicolon.